Argument of type "github" is not assignable to parameter of type 'OAuthProvider' in Appwrite

import { account } from "@/appwrite/config"
import { Button } from "./ui/button"
import { Github } from 'lucide-react'

export default function LoginButton() {
  async function handleLogin() {
    account.createOAuth2Session(
        'github',
        'http://localhost:3000/',
        'http://localhost:3000/'
    )
  }

  return (
    <Button onClick={handleLogin} className="w-full flex items-center justify-center bg-secondary text-secondary-foreground hover:bg-secondary/90 transition-colors">
      <Github className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
      Login with GitHub
    </Button>
  )
}

trying to use github as provider but it shows error that "github" is not assignable to parameter of type 'OAuthProvider' in Appwrite How can to use github as a provider

As the AppWrite docs themselves show, your first parameter in your call to createOAuth2Session should be OAuthProvider.Github:
import { OAuthProvider } from 'appwrite';
// ..

export default function LoginButton() {
  async function handleLogin() {
    account.createOAuth2Session(
        OAuthProvider.Github,
        'http://localhost:3000/',
        'http://localhost:3000/'
    )
  }

  // ...
}

It's not at all clear from where you got the idea that 'github' would be a valid parameter here.
